# Unresolved Reference when linking compiled code with NASM and MSVC

Tags: c, visual-c++, assembly, nasm, yasm

I'm trying to combine assembly (compiled with `yasm`) with objects compiled by `msvc`/`cl.exe`, which I'm trying to link (with `link.exe`) into a `.dll`, which is then linked to the final executable.

Both creating the object files from source, and creating the dll from these objects works absolutely fine.

In the last step, linking the `.dll` with the executable spits out following errors:

```
 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol xxx_xxxx
```

I'm using C. Despite Win64 having no name mangling, I tried multiple schemes (like `_xxx_xxxx` or `__imp_xxx_xxxx`).

Examining the object file with `dumpbin.exe` reveals all symbols:

```
$ dumpbin /symbols myobj.o
File Type: COFF OBJECT

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 00000000 DEBUG  notype       Filename     | .file

002 00000000 SECT1  notype       Static       | .text
Section length  215, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
004 00000057 SECT1  notype       External     | xxx_xxxx
005 0000013E SECT1  notype       External     | xxx_xxxx
006 00000000 SECT1  notype       External     | xxx_xxxx
```

But not in the exported symbols from the `.dll`:

```
$ dumpbin /exported mylib.dll
File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for mylib.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    57A0FE02 time date stamp Tue Aug 02 22:09:38 2016
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
         132 number of functions
         132 number of names

 [...]
```

Even though I have marked the declarations as exported inside the `.dll` by using `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Any ideas how to satisfy the linker and tell him the symbols are indeed there?

Comment: You can't link a DLL to an executable using Microsoft's tools. You need to use an import library that corresponds to the DLL.

Comment: @RossRidge I do use the generated import library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you see the problem is that DLL doesn't expose required symbol. `__declspec(dllexport)` is not the only way to export your symbols. If you have a few exported names you can use [`/EXPORT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k30y2k5.aspx) linker switch. Another alternative is to use [Module-Definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d91k01sh.aspx) file.

Comment: Unfortunately more than just a few functions, making `/EXPORT` unfeasible. Can I combine an already created .lib to link the dll with another create via the def file?

Comment: Yes, DEF file is just a list of functions that you wish to export (plus some extra info). It doesn't affect functionality of resulting binaries. And of course you should check that functions appear at export table with `dumpbin`.

Comment: While this works, it's unfortunately only half a solution. I can't add every symbol by hand to my build flags or the def file.

Comment: Why so? It shouldn't be more difficult than  adding dllexport specifier to each functions in source code.

Comment: It is more difficult. Requires special treatment in my makefiles, which is a pain to maintain since I have hundreds of functions I have to export.